# Computing the size of a definable set in a model from its size in its ultrapower

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, filters

Suppose $\lambda$ is a cardinal and $U$ is an regular ultrafilter on $\lambda$.   For a formula $\phi$ and a structure $M$, if $\phi(M)$ is infinite, then $|\phi(M^\lambda /U)| = |\phi(M)|^\lambda$.  From this one can conclude, e.g., if $|\phi(M)| = M$ then $|\phi(M^\lambda /U)| = |M^\lambda /U|$.

Can one reverse the direction of the converse?  From cardinal arithmetic under GCH and the assumption of $\lambda \le \operatorname{cf} \kappa$, we know that if $|\phi(M^\lambda /U)| = |M^\lambda /U|$ and $\lambda$ then $|\phi(M)| = |M|$.

My question is whether we can get rid of the assumption $\lambda \le \operatorname{cf} \kappa$, e.g., by constructing an appropriate ultrafilter.  (I tolerate GCH but would be interested if it's not necessary).

Comment: If $\phi$ is a formula, what does it mean for $\phi(M)$ to be infinite or have a cardinality $\vert\phi(M)\vert$?

Comment: @C7X $\phi(M)$ is the set of elements of the model satisfying the formula.